# how to determine if the browser supports selectionStart if there is no text selected

Tags: dom, textselection

This code will return *true* if the browser supports *selectionStart* and some text is selected, but if no text is selected it returns false (even on browsers that support it):

```
   if (el.selectionStart) {

  }
```

How do you determine if the property is available regardless of whether text happens to be selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Further googling revealed the answer:

```
 if (el.selectionStart != undefined) {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you. I tested it on an old Android 4.2 (which returns false) and Chrome (which returns true).

```
function selectionSupport() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('value', '111');
    input.selectionStart = 1;
    input.selectionEnd = 2;
    return (input.selectionStart === 1 && input.selectionEnd === 2);
}

var selectionIsSupported = selectionSupport();
```